# Swift "cannot invoke 'method_name' with an argument list of type '(protocol_name)' on generic function

Tags: swift, function, generics, protocols

I have

```
protocol A {

}

class M: A {

}

func foo<T: A>(t: T) {
    print("\(t)")
}

let m = M()
foo(m)
```

This code work as expected, but when I try to cast m to A

```
let m = M() as A
foo(m)
```

I got an error `error: cannot invoke 'foo' with an argument list of type '(A)'
foo(m)`

What did I do wrong here?

Comment: I think there is probably a better duplicate somewhere but this one is good enough.